# React-Native TabNavigator tabPress not set to active when pressed

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

when I press the 'Pako' Screen on my BottomTabNavigator I do not get the icon to highlight as the active tab. I navigate to a screen the same MainStackNavigator, used for all my tabs.

A sample of this can be found in the following snack.expo:

https://snack.expo.io/@flag81/tabnavdemo

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed some code, use `activeColor` in place of `activeTintColor`. You need not redirect to a tab page externally, you are already using the tab feature.

check my edited code here
https://snack.expo.io/@mainak-shil/tabnavdemo

Comment: I don't see any code changes that may have fixed this issue. Can you please check again on the link above.

Comment: @flag81 , sorry I pasted wrong URL, please check now with my updated URL

Comment: @maianak , thank for the reply. I appreciate it very much. With this solution I am losing the header navigation part. Is there a way to implement this solution with a stack navigator , since my app has many  screens and uses a stack-navigator.

Comment: @flag81, in that case, you can make a Header component and import into the screen that you need.

Comment: @maianak , thank for the reply. My understanding is from the research that Tab navigator does not have header-navigation options you can use.